# Easy way to compare BIOS information between two machines?

Tags: linux, shell, ssh, bios, dmidecode

I have two machines - machineA and machineB running Ubuntu 12.04

Is there any easy way I can compare BIOS settings between those two machine and see the difference instead of doing it manually using dmidecode and then comparing it which is very tedious?

I mean, can we run a shell script which gets the BIOS information from machineA and machineB and then compare both of them and tell me which component it differs and what exactly is the difference?

Comment: See `dmidecode`

Comment: @casey I already know `dmidecode`. Question was to use `dmidecode` with shell script in such a way so that you dont need to do it manually, shell script can do the comparison for you and print the difference out. If I do it manually, it is very tedious and by manually I meant, use dmidecode and then compare it on paper.